# Programmatically create TextView with ellipsis

Tags: android, textview

I'm programmatically creating a TextView that I want to ellipsis at the end.

pseudo code:

```
    tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    tv.setSingleLine();
```

The above works GREAT.

```
    tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    tv.setMaxLines(1);
```

This does not work. Is this a bug? I don't understand why I can't get text to ellipses at the end when specifying maxLines especially a maxLine of 1 but setSingleLine is ok.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`setSingleLine()` or `setSingleLine(true)` prevents the TextView from changing its height to more lines and forces the TextView to ignore line breaks (the symbol `\n` in a string).

`setMaxLines(int n)` displays the first n lines of the String displayed in the TextView which are separated by a line break.

For example let the String be "my first line \n and my second line \n and a third one"

- `setSingleLine()` lets the TextView display "my first line and my.." since the display width is exceeded and
- `setMaxLines(1)` results in "my first line"
- `setMaxLines(2)` results in "my first line" and below a line saying "and my second line"
- `setMaxLines(3)` obviously does not have any effect on this sample string.

Update: This should work for "setDoubleLine with truncation":

```
// optional: string.replace("\n",""); or string.replace("\n"," ");
tv.setSingleLine(false);
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
int n = 2; // the exact number of lines you want to display
tv.setLines(n);
```

Comment: Awesome. Is it possible to have a TextView that is two lines and still ellipse at the end? ie, setDoubleLine() etc? This is how I imagined maxLine to work. For what it's worth my height and width are set to dip values, not match_parent.

Comment: @AndreyButov thanks for suggesting an edit, I would have accepted if not asleep. I corrected the post now according to your suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Java**

```
textview.setMaxLines(maxLines); // set max lines to show
textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END); // set ellipsize postion
```

**Or Add TextView Attributes**

**XML**

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```