# Setting Ellipsize on TextView reduces lines shown by one (instead of only ellipsizing last)

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis

when I am using `TextView` with `singleLine="true"` and `ellipsize="end"`(my top TextView),
*it works well*

**but in another** `TextView` having more then 1 lines (in my case 3 lines in my bottom `TextView`),
`lines="3"  and  maxLines="3"  and  ellipsize="end",` **doesn't work properly.**

When I DON'T put `ellipsize="end"` in tvDesc, it shows 3 line, which is OK.
Here is code : XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgv"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Title testing line number and ellipsize at end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"    <---  WORKS WELL
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
                       <----------  WITHOUT ellipsize
        
        android:text="I wanna this textview of having 3 lines and ellipsize at END and at this time I am Testing for it. This TextView shows 3 lines WITHOUT ellipsize property, but shows only 2 Lines when ELLIPSIZE property is setted"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Above code shows TextView tvDesc with 3 Lines and No-Ellipsize.** Here is Image :

[image]

**But, I wanna ellipsize, so I uses followin code** : XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgv"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Title testing line number and ellipsize at end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:ellipsize="end"    <------  WITH  ELLIPSIZE
        
        android:text="I wanna this textview of having 3 lines and ellipsize at END and at this time I am Testing for it. This TextView shows 3 lines WITHOUT ellipsize property, but shows only 2 Lines when ELLIPSIZE property is setted"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Which shows TextView tvDesc with only 2 lines and Ellipsize**,

which is not properly dezired UI, as Followin:
[image]

**I wanna 3 lines in TextView tvDesc with ellipsize**

**CAN  ANYONE  HELP  ME.?**

Comment: I think you are running into a [known problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview)

Comment: I dont know exactly why this is happenning. But if you want to go with ellipsize then you keep its none property instead of end.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is by far the simplest solution I've found and am currently using in deployment. Let me know if you need any other assistance!

Oh and remember to remove the `android:ellipsize` tag in your XML since you will be using the bottom code to automatically ellipsize at the end of 3 lines.

```
TextView snippet;
snippet.setText("loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor loren ipsum dolor ")
ViewTreeObserver vto = this.snippet.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        ViewTreeObserver obs = snippet.getViewTreeObserver();
        obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        if (snippet.getLineCount() > 3) {
            int lineEndIndex = snippet.getLayout().getLineEnd(2);
            String text = snippet.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "...";
            snippet.setText(text);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This a good solution, but there is an easier and cleaner way, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me but it would be a lot easier if maxLines and ellipsize worked together.

Comment: Is it possible to add this inside a CustomTextView object to wrap all this logic and avoid adding it to every setText ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work within a ListView. The listener is not triggered when list items are swapped out with new text.

Comment: @Vishwa Patel It gives wrong value when using it with html in textview using HTML.fromHtml. Can you plz help to work it with HTML?

Comment: @Himanshu-HD, I've just tested at Android 5.0, Html.fromHtml works, but probably not in all cases.

Comment: To clarify: `snippet` is my pre-existing TextView, right? So in my case, if I'm getting `TextView notes`, I should use everything after the `setText` line and use `notes` in place of `snippet`?

Answer (score 19):

Just set `android:maxLines` and `android:ellipsize`.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_dua"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="long text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: Except it doesn't work on versions of Honeycomb. What I get is the textview sized to 2 lines, but you get the tops of the letters on the third line and no ellipsis.

Comment: Somewhere around KitKat or Lollipop this started working correctly (I forget the exact API level). Before that it still limits to the correct `maxLines` but doesn't include the ellipsis too. Still,  I think it's somewhat reasonable these days to live with this since it's a much simpler alternative to the manual string manipulation in code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to get a multiline textview with ellipsis on the last line :

```
android:maxLines="4"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="false"
```

Replace 4 with the number of lines you want.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out with maxLines and ellipsize on Android 7 & 8.

```
android:maxLines="3"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

The preview shows 2 lines and on the third line "...".

But this seems to be a bug in the previewer.

On the device it just works fine, 3 lines with text, at the end of the third line "..."

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
tv.setSingleLine(false);
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
int n = 3; // the exact number of lines you want to display
tv.setLines(n);
```

refer [Programmatically create TextView with ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087555/programmatically-create-textview-with-ellipsis)

Comment: See the edit. I missed to add the two lines. tv.setSingleLine(false); and tv.setLines(n);

Answer (score -1):

Just use **ellipsize** combined with `scrollHorizontally="true"`. Simple & clean.

It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This just makes it single line which you can already do with the `singleLine` property

Comment: @AliGangji I don't think that was the case when I posted. Good to know

Comment: For me this solution works (Android 5.0) even for multiline TextView. But number of lines changes among TextViews (from 1 to maxLines).