# Text clipping inside ListPopupWindow on Android

Tags: android

I have a ListPopupWindow defined as below in my Android application.

```
    ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;

    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(RootView.this);
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(RootView.this,
            R.layout.push_list_item, pushMessages));
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(bEvents);
    listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);
    listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    listPopupWindow.show();
```

The XML for the layout referenced above is given below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:lines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

When I get a text that is larger in size, the text just seems to clip as opposed to wrap, even though I have specified the correct attributes inside the XML. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here, and propose a solution for my problem.

Thanks..

Comment: Has an answer here, I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/23037155/1944049

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674578/multiline-textview-in-android

Comment: Kindly post a snapshot, as I tried your code it is working fine.

Comment: @avinash yes even i tried the code it seems to be ok

Answer (score 4):

The main problem you should get with your xml file that it's not possible to have >2 lines + ellipsize.

You should implement you own `EllipsizeTextView` to support real multiline ellipsized textview.

You could find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210553/setting-ellipsize-on-textview-reduces-lines-shown-by-one-instead-of-only-ellips) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173776/ellipsize-not-working-properly-for-a-multiline-textview-with-an-arbitrary-maximu).

Also you could find this [bug here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67186).