# Fade bottom of a textview android

Tags: android, textview

is there a way to fade the bottom of a TextView in Android when the text is bigger than a fixed height? I'm looking for a thing such like in the Play Store

[image]

NB: with ellipsize and fadeEdge (also combination of them) it does not work.

Comment: Have yo used android:fadingEdge

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087555/programmatically-create-textview-with-ellipsis#answer-8087718

Answer (score 5):

You can use `android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"`. To change the gradient overlay height `android:fadingEdgeLength="32dp"`

Answer (score -6):

You can find variety of textview effects [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/text-shadows/)

Comment: in the link you posted there are no effects like the one that I want

Comment: No spoon feeding my friend.. Get to know how to use "The text which gets lost in the background" and modify it to make it to your wish..