# Fading bottom of scrollable TextView

Tags: android, textview

I know that this has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333227/fade-bottom-of-a-textview-android) before but the question wasn't answered correctly. Currently, I can fade my `textView` but not the bottom but the top. In my xml:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/dummy_text"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="50dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

In my class:

```
itemDescription.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

The `@string/dummy_text` is a very long text to illustrate the scroll-ability of the `textView`. The problem here is that, initially, the bottom text in the `textView` is not faded, it shows *half the body of the characters of the text*. When you scroll the `textView`, the top texts will be faded implying that there are text above to see but the bottom texts will still not be faded so the user has no way of knowing if there are still text to see below.

I know that there are lots of questions about this, I saw them and what I have now is the product of the application of their solutions.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333227/fade-bottom-of-a-textview-android) for the image of what I want.

Comment: If you switch to using a ScrollView, then it's easy to achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39252003/56285 (if I understood you correctly).