# Fade out last few lines of a TextView

Tags: android, textview, fade, out

I've been researching all over, I was unable to find a proper answer.

I also can't achieve this on my own, so please help me out

I have a `InfoWindowDialog` view I'm creating, which has a `TextView`, that has a certain `maxHeight`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LONG_TEXT_WHICH_HAS_A_FEW_LINES..."
            android:maxHeight="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to achieve something similar to the last few lines of this example:

[image]

[image]

I have tried a solution mentioned [Fade bottom of a textview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333227/fade-bottom-of-a-textview-android)

By placing **`android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical`"** and **`android:fadingEdgeLength="32dp"`** and had no results.

Comment: Why don't you use button with text more and background with some transparency? That might help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: I was seeking for something that would eventually not have a button on top

Comment: that "more" label certainly is on top...

Comment: Why? What's reason for it? If you already think about it then you should mention in question as what you have tried and what you are looking  for.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: How about placing a faded out .png over the textview with its gravity set to bottom?

Comment: as you are noticing, this does not involve just a textview, it'll involve more than one ui element to achieve what you want

Answer (score 5):

There are a few solutions to this. The easiest is to add an UI element. Add an overlay graphic at the bottom of your view that has some sort of transparency, e.g. 50%. This will achieve what you are asking.

Others options to consider:

1) Track the last line of text, break it up, and add 50% transparency to it.

2) Track the last line of text, break it up, and change the color to a different gray. This gives the impression of transparency

3) If using scrollview, they have fading edge features.

```
<ScrollView android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">
```

and in your code, you can do the following

```
ScrollView scroll = findById(); scroll.setFadingEdgeLength(150);
```

OR in your XML use `android:fadingEdgeLength="150dp"`. Cheers!