# Limiting a String to 2 lines in android, then cut it and concatenate a String

Tags: android, string, textview, concatenation, lines

My question may sound a bit weird but I'll try to explain it better here.

I ahve a TextView in android, at the inferior part of my activity. I want to have it limited to 2 lines, which is easily reachable by adding the following line in the TextView xml element:

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

Okay, now we've got it limited to 2 lines. 
Then, in my Activity, I make:

```
termsandconditions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
termsandconditions.setText(terms);
```

Okay, now I've got a big string with the terms and conditions, but limited to 2 lines due to the xml attribute.

Now my question is, how can I cut it after having it limited to 2 lines, and concatenate a string with "Read more"? I don't need it to be in the same textView or whatever, I only want that it looks like:

Terms: blablablalblalbla blal  blablalblalblalblalbla  lalblalblalblalblalblalb lalblalblalb lalblalblalblalblalb lalblalblalb lalblalblalblalb lalb bla View More.

Thanks and I hope you can understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt where)` method of `TextView` or the `android:ellipsize` XML attribute.

> public void setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt where) Added in API
>   level 1
>
> Causes words in the text that are longer than the view is wide to be
>   ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. You may also want to
>   setSingleLine() or setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean) to constrain the
>   text to a single line. Use null to turn off ellipsizing. If
>   setMaxLines(int) has been used to set two or more lines, END and
>   MARQUEE* are only supported (other ellipsizing types will not do
>   anything).
>
> Related XML Attributes
>
> ```
> android:ellipsize
> ```

Comment: Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087555/programmatically-create-textview-with-ellipsis

Comment: Thanks!! I think it will work, I'll try it and vote as soon as I get home!!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit hacky, but here's my suggestion:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="your_text_view"
            android:text="long long long text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="link"
            android:text="View More"
            android:onClick="addMoreLinesAndHideThisTextView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Some additional tweaking may be needed, but I think you got the idea.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your idea, in case the upper one didn't work I'll try this!