# Fade the last line in a multi-line TextView

Tags: android, textview

Is there any solution to fade the last line in a multi-lint TextView? As the following effects:

[image: TextView with fade effect]

Comment: try this http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/

Comment: did you managed how to do it?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087555/programmatically-create-textview-with-ellipsis#answer-8087718

Answer (score -2):

You can set Textview property as changemaxlines according.

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```